# jquery Multiselect

Tags: jquery

how to sort jquery multiselect based on  selected values???    I would like to show selected option first in jquery multiselect, followed by all unselected vales.

```
    like below multiselect  having two values selected

    <select id="the-select">
        <option value="1">First option</option> \\selected
        <option value="2">Second option</option>
    <option value="3">Third option</option>\\selected
    </select>


   but i need to show the multiselect as its showing below

    <select id="the-select">
        <option value="1">First option</option> \\selected   
    <option value="3">Third option</option>\\selected
     <option value="2">Second option</option>
    </select>

    Thanks
```

Comment: note that this can work when you parse your page the first time, but please be careful with 'on-the-fly' sorting. For users it can be very confusing when the order of the options changes each time they select one. Consider sorting your options in a intuitive way, eg alphabetic.

Comment: thanks for reply.I need to sort at the time of loading only....i mean when page load first time. would appreciate if you can share sample code with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution in 3 lines:

```
var selected = $("select[name=yourselectname] option:selected"); //get every selected option
selected.remove(); //remove them from the select
$("select[name=yourselectname]").prepend(selected); //add them at the beginning of the select
```

Tested and approuved :-)

Comment: Thanks for reply but i think you didn't get my question.I want to show all selected values first in multiselect then all unselected values.

Comment: That's what it does :-). Try it !

Comment: Yeah i tried the same but didn't work :( here is my code     $("#positionId").multiselect();   //comment Start:id and name is same,and that is= positionId Comment end//                                               var selected = $("select[name=positionId] option:selected");
    selected.remove();            
            $("select[name=positionId]").prepend(selected);

Comment: I haven't seen you were using jQuery multiselect. You may try $("yourselect").multiselect("refresh");

Comment: Actually i m new to stackoverflow...i searched for voting up and did:) would like to confirm the same with you

Comment: You may need to have more reputation to vote up. But you can't set this answer as best answer ?

Comment: now i have enough reputation to make it +1 :) so did the same